# In Gerrit, how can I push arbitrary tags to non-standard locations?

Tags: gerrit

I would like to push build tags to a non-standard location on gerrit, mainly to avoid them from showing up as an official tag and also to avoid polluting users with a bunch of build tags.

On old versions of gerrit, I was able to grant myself permissions to create refs and tags in, say, `refs/builds/tags/*`, and then do

```
git push origin refs/tags/BUILD-123:refs/builds/tags/BUILD-123
```

The beauty of the scheme is that this way, the build tags don't pollute ordinary users' git repos, but if someone is interested in the build tags, they can run:

```
git fetch origin 'refs/builds/tags/*:refs/tags/*'
```

and then all the build tags appear and become usable as tags.

It seems that on newer versions of gerrit (2.16?) direct push is limited to the standard locations.

It also appears as if one can only push tags of commits which are direct ancestors an existing branch, so if my build does anything unusual (for example rebase to the tip), it fails.

Is this configurable anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is no such restriction, you just have to grant yourself all the required permissions, like so:

```
[access "refs/builds/*"]
    create = <me>
    createSignedTag = <me>
    createTag = <me>
    delete = <me>
    read = <me>
```

I forgot to give myself read permissions...

The restriction that *does* exist is where you cannot push a tag that is not for a commit that is an ancestor of an existing known branch. The reason this restriction exists is because access to commits is controlled via ACLs that feature wild carded refs as primary key to permissions. If someone knew a "forbidden" sha and was allowed to push a tag, this scheme can be bypassed.

The trick is to **give up on pushing tags and to push branches instead**. Branches can be pushed to non-standard locations just like tags, and if someone fetches them into `refs/tags`, they also act like lightweight tags.